# Keep the original checkbox status

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have a checkbox

```
  <telerik:GridViewColumn Width="40" Header="Something" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                        <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Order,Converter={StaticResource ShortToBooleanConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          Click="CheckBox_Checked">

                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

In the click event in code behind.

```
  private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
```

I want to display some message if condition fails.

> var message = "You cannot update it".

In this case I want to keep the original checkbox status/ For example, if it was checked, by clicking it. It is unckecked. But as the condition fails, I want to keep it as checked.

What is the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `CheckBox_Checked` you can simply do this:

```
var cb = (CheckBox)sender;

if (!canProceed)
{
    cb.Checked = !cb.Checked
}
```

But the better approach is to to disable `CheckBox` when it shouldn't be changed. You can also use converter, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223062/how-to-run-a-code-before-fired-change-check-in-a-checkbox-in-wpf) for more details.